# Data Audit Trail with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am writing a product inventory tracker application and I am trying to create a data audit trail on each stock.  Whenever a stock is modified, I want a copy of it stored in another table including who edited it.  The problem is that there's a dynamic set of **CustomProperties** that needs to be stored as well.  What would be the best way to track changes? my first thought is to just create a table with identical fields.

Currently my inventory class is stored like this.

```
public class Inventory
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomInventoryProperty> CustomProperties { get; set; } 
}
```

And the Custom Properties are stored like this

```
public class CustomInventoryProperty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomPropertyID { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public virtual Inventory Inventory { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: If you need real Audit I would not use code stuff but would maybe use CDC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627369.aspx

Comment: And your post isn't really a question, so please give us some more infos.

Comment: @gsharp - Even with cdc you would have to use some custom code/packages to transfer them to permanent tables as temp data is flushed out after few days.

Comment: Yeah this was why I didn't use that, I ended up just duplicating the class with HistoryID as its key and manually transferred the record that got edited over to the History table.